# How to add multiple devices to provisioning profile at a time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I have more than 40 devices. If I add devices one by one it will take so much time. So I want to add all these devices to one provisioning profile at a time. Is there any way to add **multiple devices** at a time.

Comment: you can add name and device id on txt file and upload

Comment: Thanks Venkat,  Could you please give format for the text file?

Comment: refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Comment: in developer portal itself you will have sample text file.